# Getting information out of ConstraintViolationException - Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

I'm using Jersey 2.19 to implement a REST API.

I enabled `ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE` to transform `ConstraintViolationException` into validation errors. This is working. In addition to the response code I get some text in the response that looks like:

`Parameter value must be 'true' or 'false' (path = MyResource.m_myParam, invalidValue = invalid)`.

I have also created a custom exception mapper to map `ConstraintViolationExceptions` to a particular HTTP response code of my choosing.

This is also working.

However, I note that the additional information is no longer present int he response. If I call `getMessage` on the exception it returns `null`.

How do I get access to the same information in my mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call [`ConstraintViolationException.getConstraintViolations()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html#getConstraintViolations--) which will return a `Set<ConstraintViolation>`. Take a look at the [`ConstraintViolation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html) API to see all the information you have access to.

The particular message you are showings is a String built from information obtained through `getMessage()`, `getPropertyPath()`, and `getInvalidValue()` of the `ConstraintViolation`